# Missing article?

Tags: grammar, verbs, articles

Should there be an article before the word *cruelty* in the sentence below?

> Nevertheless, Gandhi knew that cruelty was not the answer and stated, “An eye for an eye will only make the whole world blind.”

Comment: No, _cruelty_ is an abstract noun and therefore is not individuated. If you're speaking of the cruelty of a particular act by a person, it can be definite, but it can't be a singular count noun. _Cruelties_ as a mass plural is not uncommon, but it just means _a lot of cruelty_ (_the cruelties of their captors_).

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: No. Why do you think an article is needed? Have you got the intended meaning of the sentence correct?

Comment: In some languages, the definite article is used to differentiate between the verb form and the gerund/verbal-noun/participle form. Such that "She is-cruel to me" vs "Her the-cruel to me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nevertheless, Gandhi knew that cruelty was not the answer and stated, "An eye for an eye will only make the whole world blind."

In this sentence, the author is referring to *cruelty* in general, rather than a specific instance.

The [Frankfort International School corroborates](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/article.htm):

> You use an uncount noun with no article if you mean that thing in general.

Comment: That's for [ell.se] or a primer on English grammar, right?